# Synchronize between an MS Access (Jet / MADB) database and PostgreSQL DB, is this possible?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, backend, database-mirroring

Is it possible to have a MS access backend database (Microsoft JET or Access Database Engine) set up so that whenever entries are inserted/updated those changes are replicated<sup>*</sup> to a PostgreSQL database?

Two-way synchronization would be nice, but one way would be acceptable.

I know it's popular to link the two and use one as a frontend, but it's essential that both be backend.

Any suggestions?

---

<sup>*</sup> ie reflected, synchronized, mirrored

Comment: Should be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991/using-ms-access-odbc-to-connect-to-a-remote-postgresql

Comment: no that doesn't really help me, as I mentioned lots of people use one database as a backend and then pull information through it using the other.  Like in the link you provided access is merely a front.  I need both databases to be backends, but merely mirror each other.

Comment: Since it appears that you can link Postgres, it means that you can run queries to update Postgres with data from MS Access. Unless you are using a front-end of some description, I don't think you can do this in real time.

Comment: Specifying the Access version and the exact backend you are using would help.

Comment: Database 1: Access 2002 backend vb6 frontend.
Database 2: postgreSQL (we can use something else like MS SQL Server).

Comment: So what did you end up doing? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use [Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx)? Or do you have to use [Microsoft Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)? It's possible you'll have more options using MS SQL express, like more complete triggers and logging.

Either way, you're going to need a way to accumulate a log of changed rows from the source database engine, and a program to sync them to PostgreSQL by reading the log and converting it into suitable PostgreSQL `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements.

You could do this by having audit triggers in MADB/Express insert a row into an audit shadow table for every "real" table whenever it changed, including inserting special "row deleted" audit entries. Then your sync program could connect to both MADB/Express, read the audit tables, apply the changes to PostgreSQL, and empty the audit tables.

I'll be surprised if you find anything to do this out of the box. It's one area where Microsoft SQL Server has a big advantage because of all the deep Access and MADB engine integation to support the synchronisation and integration features.

There are some ETL ("Extract, Transform, Load") tools that might be helpful, like [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/) and [Talend](http://www.talend.com/resource/etl.html). I don't know if you can achieve the desired degree of automation with them though.